# What does 回 do in 这回事?

Tags: measure-word

I have come across quite a few instance of 这回事(儿) instead of 这件事.

Is there is a real difference between the two, or is it just a syntactical preference of the speaker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [回](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/833/)
>
> [6] (measure) time (as used to indicate number of occurrence)
>
> [7] (measure) piece (as used for happenings or events)

回 is a measure word for event or occurrence ; 这回事 means "**this** (*piece of*) **event**" or "**this** (*time of*) **occurrence**"

Different between 回 and 件 as measure word is:

- 回 measure specific course of events (*how many times it happens*)
- 件 measure event as an unit (*how many of it exists*)

> 就是这一回事 = it is this occurrence
>
> 當沒有这回事 = pretend there is no such occurrence

~

> 就是这一件事 = It is this event
>
> 當沒有这件事 = pretend this event doesn't exist

We also say 这回战斗(This battle) or 这回会谈(this discussion) ; but not 这件战斗 or 这件会谈.

Answer (score 0):

这回事儿 is equal to 这件事儿 in Chinese, but 这回事儿 is used more often in spoken language.